# React Native - Under render can navigate but not in navigation bar

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navigation, react-navigation

This is my `Booking.js` codes.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, View, ScrollView, Alert, } from 'react-native';
import { Button } from 'react-native-elements';

class Booking extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Booking',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerBackTitle: 'Back',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'black', },
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Bnew') }}
        title='New'
        color='white'
        backgroundColor='black'
      />
    ),
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.boohis}>
          <Button
            onPress={() => { Alert.alert("", "Upcoming is Coming Soon!") }}
            title='Upcoming'
            color='white'
            backgroundColor='black'
            style={{ width: 185, margin:1 }}
          />
          <Button
            onPress={() => { Alert.alert("", "History is Coming Soon!") }}
            title='History'
            color='white'
            backgroundColor='black'
            style={{ width: 185, margin:1 }}
          />
        </View>
        <View style={styles.container2}>
          <ScrollView contentContainerStyle={{ justifyContent: 'space-between', padding: 3, alignItems: 'center' }}>
            <Button
              title='New'
              fontWeight='bold'
              buttonStyle={{ borderRadius: 15, backgroundColor: '#10a366', height: 50, width: 300, margin: 15 }}
              onPress={() => { this.props.navigation.navigate('Bnew') }}
            />
          </ScrollView>
        </View>
      </View>
    )
  }
}

export default Booking;
```

This is the look of my `Booking.js`.

[image: Booking.js]

This is the error that show out.

[image: error]

The error came out because I press the `NEW` button on the navigation bar
but when I click on the green `New` button it will navigate to the page I want.

In my render the navigation is work but not on my navigation bar.

What's the problem here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot access `this` from a `static` method. You have to use the `navigation` object that `navigationOptions` receives.

So your `navigationOptions` should look like this.

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  return {
    title: 'Booking',
    headerTintColor: 'white',
    headerBackTitle: 'Back',
    headerStyle: { backgroundColor: 'black' },
    headerRight: (
      <Button
        onPress={() => {
          navigation.navigate('Bnew');
        }}
        title='New'
        color='white'
        backgroundColor='black'
      />
    ),
  };

};
```

Comment: Can I view any documentation? I want to watch it.

Comment: Yeah, of course. Here it goes, https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/navigation-options-resolution.html#docsNav / https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#sharing-common-navigationoptions-across-screens